# Passing the list of input$map_click inside shinyapp

Tags: shiny

I'm trying to collect the latitude and longitude values of a map click inside of a shinnyApp - using leaflet.  I can print the values as text but cannot seem to access the values for use inside the application to be passed for further use. My simple two lines of code is listed below.

```
place <- reactive(input$map_click)
output$Click_text<-renderText(paste0(place()))
```

Using:
`fluidRow(verbatimTextOutput("Click_text"))` - I'm able to print the values to a screen.

But when I use:
    `p <- place$lat`
I get the following error -  `Error in place$lat : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable.`

It's my first post - I've used stackoverflow for 2 years. I am crediting this other post for helping so far:

[Passing user input in Shiny to a URL query string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36311562/passing-user-input-in-shiny-to-a-url-query-string)